# How to save all sequentially captured image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to save all the captured images in MATLAB but I am able to save one picture at a time.

```
mycam = webcam();
img = snapshot(mycam);
imwrite(img,'img.jpg');
```

If somebody knows how to save all the pictures taken at a time in MATLAB, please help me with the code.

Comment: Use a loop‍‍‍‍‍.‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: On top of using a loop, make sure the filename is distinct at each iteration or you're just going to be overwriting the same file.

Comment: thank  you for your reply.
 i used  but am not getting the required result. all the time   saving the last frame  of the sequence.

Comment: thank  you for your reply.
 i used (but not getting how to use the loop here) but am not getting the required result. all the time saving the last frame  of the sequence.i did this way....

 mycam = webcam();
img = snapshot(mycam);
frame = 10;
for i = 1:frame
imwrite(img,'img.jpg');
end

Comment: can you reply with the  code

Comment: Hint. Use `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

As they have already told you, you should use a `for` loop with the `sprintf` function in order to not overwrite the previous images. Try with the following command:

```
    %capture the frames
    for i =1:n;% n is the number of frames you want to capture
        frames{i} = getsnapshot(mycam);
    end
    %save in the current folder
    for i = 1:n; 
        imwrite(frames{i}, sprintf('imageName%d.jpg',i))
    end
```

You will have all the captured frames saved in the Current Folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the images as a movie and then access the frames later.  This is untested but it would work like this.

```
mycam = webcam();
% if you know the number of images use that here
% a movie is just a collection of frames
% if not then just don't initialize F
F(nFrames) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap, []);
for i = 1:nFrames
    F(i) = im2frame(snapshot(mycam));
end
% save F
movie2avi(F, 'MyMovie.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

Then you can load the movie and look at the frames.  This example uses the older `movie2avi` but `VideoWriter` is also an option

```
v = VideoWriter('MyMovie.avi');
open(v);
for i = 1:nFrames
    writeVideo(v, snapshot(mycam));
end
close(v);
```

Again untested as I don't have a webcam attached to this computer.  But it works for animated graphs.  See `doc readFrame` for the way to read frames